# specific columns of selected row for print

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

How to set specific columns of selected row  for print ? Google Apps Script - Google Sheets

Where I select a row of the google sheet, the data of these columns should be printed by the macro ("A", "B", "J", "S").

I've written this macro to select rows but I don't know how to make more changes required

```
function print() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getMaxColumns()).activate();

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- When you select a cell, you want to retrieve the values of the specific columns of the row of the selected cell.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function print() {
  var selectColumns = ["A", "B", "J", "S"]; // This is from your question.
  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var currentRow = sheet.getCurrentCell().getRow();
  var columnIndex = selectColumns.map(letter => [...letter.toUpperCase()].reduce((c, e, i, a) => (c += (e.charCodeAt(0) - 64) * Math.pow(26, a.length - i - 1)), -1));
  var values = sheet.getRange(currentRow, 1, 1, sheet.getMaxColumns()).getValues().map(r => columnIndex.map(c => r[c]))[0].join(",");
  console.log(values) // Here, you can also confirm the values in the log.
  Browser.msgBox(values); // You can see the values at a dialog of Spreadsheet.
}
```

- When you select a cell and run this script, the values of the specific columns `"A", "B", "J", "S"` of the row of the selected cell are retrieved.
- At `columnIndex`, the column letters are converted to the column indexes.
- From `sheet.getRange(spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getMaxColumns()).activate();`, if you want to activate the specific columns, how about the following modification?

  ```
    function print2() {
      var selectColumns = ["A", "B", "J", "S"]; // This is from your question.
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      var currentRow = sheet.getCurrentCell().getRow();
      sheet.getRangeList(selectColumns.map(e => e + currentRow)).activate();
    }
  ```

#### Reference:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

### Added 1:

From your following reply,

> I mean when i using function print2() if selectColumns = ["A", "B", "C" ] , Cells A B C are highlighted And that's great. but when i try To Use CTRL + P and And I make the settings related to print the selected cells, I only see cell c in the print output

First, in this case, it is required to select the continuous ranges like "A1:C1". When the cells "A1:C1" and "E1" are selected, only "E1" is shown. And, when the cells are selected using RangeList, the cells are selected for every cell. I thought that this might be the reason for your current issue. So, when you want to use the selected cells using the printer setting, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

When you use this script, please set `startColumn` and `endColumn`. And, please select a cell. And, please run the script. By this, in this sample, the columns "A" to "C" are selected. When you push `CTRL + P` and do `the settings related to print the selected cells`, you can see the 3 cells.

```js
function print3() {
  var startColumn = "A"; // Please set the start column.
  var endColumn = "C"; // Please set the end column.

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var currentRow = sheet.getCurrentCell().getRow();
  sheet.getRange(`${startColumn}${currentRow}:${endColumn}${currentRow}`).activate();
}
```

### Added 2:

If you want to use the discrete columns and cells, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

**This script uses Sheets API. So, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).**

When you use this script, please set `selectColumns`. In this case, you can set the discrete columns. And, please select a cell, and run the script of `print4`. By this, only the columns of `selectColumns` of the selected row are shown. By this, when you push `CTRL + P`, you can see the showing cells. This is another workaround for achieving your goal.

After your work is finished, when you run `showAll`, all rows and columns are shown.

```js
function print4() {
  var selectColumns = ["A", "B", "J", "S"]; // This is from your question.

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var currentRow = sheet.getCurrentCell().getRow();
  var columnIndex = selectColumns.map(letter => [...letter.toUpperCase()].reduce((c, e, i, a) => (c += (e.charCodeAt(0) - 64) * Math.pow(26, a.length - i - 1)), -1));

  var sheetId = sheet.getSheetId();
  var requests = [...Array(sheet.getMaxColumns())].reduce((ar, _, i) => {
    if (!columnIndex.includes(i)) {
      ar.push({ updateDimensionProperties: { range: { sheetId, startIndex: i, endIndex: i + 1, dimension: "COLUMNS" }, properties: { hiddenByUser: true }, fields: "hiddenByUser" } });
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);
  var maxRows = sheet.getMaxRows();
  if (currentRow == 1) {
    requests.push({ updateDimensionProperties: { range: { sheetId, startIndex: currentRow, endIndex: maxRows, dimension: "ROWS" }, properties: { hiddenByUser: true }, fields: "hiddenByUser" } });
  } else if (currentRow == maxRows) {
    requests.push({ updateDimensionProperties: { range: { sheetId, startIndex: 0, endIndex: maxRows - 1, dimension: "ROWS" }, properties: { hiddenByUser: true }, fields: "hiddenByUser" } });
  } else {
    requests.push({ updateDimensionProperties: { range: { sheetId, startIndex: 0, endIndex: currentRow - 1, dimension: "ROWS" }, properties: { hiddenByUser: true }, fields: "hiddenByUser" } });
    requests.push({ updateDimensionProperties: { range: { sheetId, startIndex: currentRow, endIndex: maxRows, dimension: "ROWS" }, properties: { hiddenByUser: true }, fields: "hiddenByUser" } });
  }
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({ requests }, ss.getId());
}

function showAll() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const requests = [{ updateDimensionProperties: { range: { sheetId: sheet.getSheetId(), dimension: "COLUMNS" }, properties: { hiddenByUser: false }, fields: "hiddenByUser" } }, { updateDimensionProperties: { range: { sheetId: sheet.getSheetId(), dimension: "ROWS" }, properties: { hiddenByUser: false }, fields: "hiddenByUser" } }];
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({ requests }, ss.getId());
}
```

Comment: with print 2 function  my problem solved but when i printed cells just last cell printed

Comment: I mean when i using function print2() if selectColumns = ["A", "B", "C" ] , Cells A B C are highlighted And that's great. but when i try To Use CTRL + P and And I make the settings related to print the selected cells, I only see cell c in the print output – @Tanaike

Comment: @ali dehqani Thank you for replying. Now, I understood your reply and your current issue. In this case, it might be required to use a workaround. So, can you give me time?

Comment: @ali dehqani I added one more sample script for your reply. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: @ali dehqani I added one more sample script. The added sample script is a workaround for using discrete columns and cells. If that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: last sample error : print4 ReferenceError: Sheets is not definedDetails

Comment: oops sheet api was disabled ! thanks bro my problem solved very very thanks

Comment: @ali dehqani Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.